R terra, plot a stack of rasters with different colour maps, one for categorical, another for numerical rasters
I want to plot two rasters that are in the same stack with my custom colours, or in other words, a raster with two layers. One of the layers has continuos values. The other contains categorical values (values or levels: 1,2,3,4).
When I set the colour map like this and plot:
mycolors <- c("#F2F2F2", "#ECB176", "#00e600", "#00A600")
plot(result_raster, col = mycolors)

I obtain the expected colours in the layer with categorical values but the continuous raster, instead of a gradient of colours, the only four colours are used.
How can I keep the default terra colours in the continuos raster, while keeping my custom colours in the other, so that I can get the plots arranged in one window as usual for stack rasters?
Here is a reproducible example.
First load an example raster:
rasterfile <- system.file("ex/elev.tif", package = "terra")
rcont <- rast(rasterfile)
plot(rcont)


Then I create a discrete raster:
rdis <- rcont

rdis <- classify(rdis,
              cbind(before = c(0:250),
                    after = 1))
rdis <- classify(rdis,
              cbind(before = c(251:350),
                    after = 2))
rdis <- classify(rdis,
              cbind(before = c(351:400),
                    after = 3))
rdis <- classify(rdis,
              cbind(before = c(401:600),
                    after = 4))
plot(rdis)


Now, I stack them in the same raster:
mystack <- c(rcont, rdis)
plot(mystack)


And add my custom colors:
mycolors <- c("#0000005c", "#ECB176", "#00e600", "#00A600")

plot(mystack, col = mycolors)


Notice how I lose the gradient colors in the continuous plot.

I don't see how your assignment to mycolors is going to affect your plot call in any way. Do you need to pass it to the plot function? I don't think that will actually answer your Q of making individual raster layers plot differently, but it looks wrong.

Thanks @Spacedman, for letting me know about that. I forgot to include the col argument in the plot function. Now it's fixed. See above.

Some code to simulate a raster of the same general form and values as your data would help - just a 10x10x4 raster maybe, made up of three continuous (-5,3) layers and one discrete {1,2,3,4} values?

Thanks, @Spacedman. I added a reproducible example. I changed the question to make it just for two layers. The problem would exactly the same as with 15 layers, I think,

Apart from what @spacedman suggested, one can use coltab() from the terra package to set colours for each layer individually.
Again, to show a reproducible example, here are a few code chunks to create the rasters:
Using a built-in terra map:
rasterfile <- system.file("ex/elev.tif", package = "terra")

rcont <- rast(rasterfile)

plot(rcont)

Create the example discrete raster:
rdis <- rcont

rdis <- classify(rdis,
                 cbind(before = c(0:250),
                       after = 1))
rdis <- classify(rdis,
                 cbind(before = c(251:350),
                       after = 2))
rdis <- classify(rdis,
                 cbind(before = c(351:400),
                       after = 3))
rdis <- classify(rdis,
                 cbind(before = c(401:600),
                       after = 4))
plot(rdis)

Create a raster with two layers (also called a stack):
mystack <- c(rcont, rdis)
mynames <- names(mystack)  #A backup of the names, see below the reason.
plot(mystack)

Define the colours:
mycolors <- data.frame(values = c(1,2,3,4),
                        cols = c("#0000005c", "#ECB176", "#00e600", "#00A600"))

It's necessary to define the levels of the categorical raster. Otherwise the legend is not shown in the plot:
mylevels <- data.frame(values = c(1,2,3,4),
                       cats = c("very low", "low", "medium", "high"))

levels(mystack[[2]]) <- mylevels

Use coltab() to define the colours of each layer:
coltab(mystack, layer = 2) <- mycolors
names(mystack) <- mynames #Names are lost, so recover them.
plot(mystack)


The figure above shows the continuous map on the left panel and the categorical map on the right panel. The continuous map doesn't have a custom colour map and so it takes the terra default colours. The categorical maps shows my custom colours.

Its done exactly what you asked - plot both using just those four colours. I don't see a way to specify different colour palettes for individual layers in a raster (eg suppose you wanted layer 1 in reds, layer 2 in greens, layer 3 in blue to show the effect of an RGB stack). It "works" in the default case because the default colour palette has 100 entries, and the discrete palette raster only shows four of them. If you could make a 100 colour palette that happened to have the four colours you wanted for your discrete layer and was the correct colours for your continuous layer then you could specify that.
eg  plot(mystack, col=map.pal("rainbow",100)) will show both layers with a rainbow palette, but the first as a continuous (or at least nearly, with 100 colours) palette and the second with four colours from that palette.
The alternative is to use par(mfrow=c(2,2)) or similar to set a 2x2 plot layout, and do each one separately. Then you have full individual control of the col parameter.
> par(mfrow=c(2,2))
> plot(rcont, col=map.pal("rainbow",100))
> plot(rcont, col=map.pal("viridis",100))
> plot(rcont, col=rev(map.pal("viridis",100)))
> plot(rdis, col=mycolors)



Thank you very much @Spacedman for your reply. I like the idea of making independent plots, but joining them using par(). I happend to find another possible solution: using coltab(), which lets you choose the colors for each layer individually. I'll add it as another possible answer.
